# MVC FormsAuthentication time out - AJAX considerations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, timeout, forms-authentication

Hope you can help. In my ASP.net MVC3 app, all my controllers descend from a customized controller I have created.

Upon FormsAuthentication time out, my app correctly redirects users to the login page if they attempt to access any page (standard functionality).

However, for Ajax.ActionLink and Ajax.BeginForm calls, they just return nothing, which confuses users if the browser is left open for more than 20 minutes and then they try to access an Ajax link.

Is there any code I can put in to my base controller that will work generically so that when it detects an inbound Ajax call and we have timed-out, it will redirect users to my login page as expected?

I don't mind if it doesn't return to the original page afterwards - happy for it to just go to the Home Index page.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Simon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may take a look at the [following blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/04/prevent-forms-authentication-login-page-redirect-when-you-donrsquot-want.aspx) which illustrates a nice way to prevent the FormsAuthentication module from redirecting to the logon page in case of an AJAX request and simply send a 401 status code to the client so that it can act accordingly.

Comment: Hi @Darin, thank you for your response. Actually, it's the opposite behaviour I want - I would like my app to always go back to the login page, regardless of whether it's an Ajax or regular call. I don't want to have to responde to a 401 in every AJAX call I make - I want it to be standard behaviour built in to my base controller. And because Ajax forms generally render a portion of the page in a div, I need my Login form to be a full page redirection - not to be displayed in the div section. Thanks, Simon.

Comment: @Simon, the thing is that when you use AJAX and if your server doesn't return 401 status code you have no way of knowing whether you god redirected to the logon page (because the session expired) or if you got served the correct page. In both cases you get 200 status code and HTML. So you can't act accordingly. If you configure your server to return 401 status code in case of expired session you will be able to use `window.location.href` in your AJAX 401 error callback because you will know that the session expired and simply redirect the browser to the logon page.

Comment: Hi Darin, thanks for your advice. My next question would then be, how can I set up this behaviour by default? I have literally hundreds of AJAX calls peppered throughout my app. I really don't want to have to specifically handle this condition in every one manually. Is there a way to set this default behaviour up, perhaps using JQuery?

Comment: @Simon, you could subscribe for a global [`.ajaxError()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/) handler on your page so that if an error is triggered during any of your ajax calls you will be able to handle it on a single centralized location. So you will check for the HTTP status code and if it is 401 you will redirect to the logon page.

Comment: Thanks @Darin. Much appreciated. I only have rep 13 so I can't vote up your answer yet. +1 if I could!!!